# How to remove popup message of NFC tag in iOS?

Tags: ios, nfc

In the give image, when NFC session begin, "Ready to scan" popup appear in screen. In my application I only need to scan NFC tag without popup. Is there any solution to remove popup as shown in image?

[image]

Comment: No, it is shown by iOS.

Comment: thanks paulw11 for quick response.Is there any option to remove popup of nfc tag.I have implement self.nfcMessages.append([])  and it only remove message after nfc tag is detected.

Comment: As I said. No. It is presented by Core NFC when you initiate a scan

Comment: Any update on this? Is it still impossible today?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible with current API. I've had several discussions with Apple direct about their NFC implementation which I specifically brought up the system UI modal and if it can be disabled from showing. They basically told me it'll never happen.

If you want to consider accessing private functions then I think it is possible but your app get approved for the iTunes Store.

Comment: Curious if they changed their position since they release NFC background reading.